How does Curve Finance `_checkpoint` works? Especially the for loop
The code is converted to solidity but why it was implemented this way.
    function _checkpoint(
        uint _tokenId,
        LockedBalance memory old_locked,
        LockedBalance memory new_locked
    ) internal {
        Point memory u_old;
        Point memory u_new;
        int128 old_dslope = 0;
        int128 new_dslope = 0;
        uint _epoch = epoch;

        if (_tokenId != 0) {
            // Calculate slopes and biases
            // Kept at zero when they have to
            if (old_locked.end > block.timestamp && old_locked.amount > 0) {
                u_old.slope = old_locked.amount / iMAXTIME;
                u_old.bias = u_old.slope * int128(int256(old_locked.end - block.timestamp));
            }
            if (new_locked.end > block.timestamp && new_locked.amount > 0) {
                u_new.slope = new_locked.amount / iMAXTIME;
                u_new.bias = u_new.slope * int128(int256(new_locked.end - block.timestamp));
            }

            // Read values of scheduled changes in the slope
            // old_locked.end can be in the past and in the future
            // new_locked.end can ONLY by in the FUTURE unless everything expired: than zeros
            old_dslope = slope_changes[old_locked.end];
            if (new_locked.end != 0) {
                if (new_locked.end == old_locked.end) {
                    new_dslope = old_dslope;
                } else {
                    new_dslope = slope_changes[new_locked.end];
                }
            }
        }

        Point memory last_point = Point({bias: 0, slope: 0, ts: block.timestamp, blk: block.number});
        if (_epoch > 0) {
            last_point = point_history[_epoch];
        }
        uint last_checkpoint = last_point.ts;
        // initial_last_point is used for extrapolation to calculate block number
        // (approximately, for *At methods) and save them
        // as we cannot figure that out exactly from inside the contract
        Point memory initial_last_point = last_point;
        uint block_slope = 0; // dblock/dt
        if (block.timestamp > last_point.ts) {
            block_slope = (MULTIPLIER * (block.number - last_point.blk)) / (block.timestamp - last_point.ts);
        }
        // If last point is already recorded in this block, slope=0
        // But that's ok b/c we know the block in such case

        // Go over weeks to fill history and calculate what the current point is
        {
            uint t_i = (last_checkpoint / WEEK) * WEEK;
            for (uint i = 0; i < 255; ++i) {
                // Hopefully it won't happen that this won't get used in 5 years!
                // If it does, users will be able to withdraw but vote weight will be broken
                t_i += WEEK;
                int128 d_slope = 0;
                if (t_i > block.timestamp) {
                    t_i = block.timestamp;
                } else {
                    d_slope = slope_changes[t_i];
                }
                last_point.bias -= last_point.slope * int128(int256(t_i - last_checkpoint));
                last_point.slope += d_slope;
                if (last_point.bias < 0) {
                    // This can happen
                    last_point.bias = 0;
                }
                if (last_point.slope < 0) {
                    // This cannot happen - just in case
                    last_point.slope = 0;
                }
                last_checkpoint = t_i;
                last_point.ts = t_i;
                last_point.blk = initial_last_point.blk + (block_slope * (t_i - initial_last_point.ts)) / MULTIPLIER;
                _epoch += 1;
                if (t_i == block.timestamp) {
                    last_point.blk = block.number;
                    break;
                } else {
                    point_history[_epoch] = last_point;
                }
            }
        }

        epoch = _epoch;
        // Now point_history is filled until t=now

        if (_tokenId != 0) {
            // If last point was in this block, the slope change has been applied already
            // But in such case we have 0 slope(s)
            last_point.slope += (u_new.slope - u_old.slope);
            last_point.bias += (u_new.bias - u_old.bias);
            if (last_point.slope < 0) {
                last_point.slope = 0;
            }
            if (last_point.bias < 0) {
                last_point.bias = 0;
            }
        }

        // Record the changed point into history
        point_history[_epoch] = last_point;

        if (_tokenId != 0) {
            // Schedule the slope changes (slope is going down)
            // We subtract new_user_slope from [new_locked.end]
            // and add old_user_slope to [old_locked.end]
            if (old_locked.end > block.timestamp) {
                // old_dslope was <something> - u_old.slope, so we cancel that
                old_dslope += u_old.slope;
                if (new_locked.end == old_locked.end) {
                    old_dslope -= u_new.slope; // It was a new deposit, not extension
                }
                slope_changes[old_locked.end] = old_dslope;
            }

            if (new_locked.end > block.timestamp) {
                if (new_locked.end > old_locked.end) {
                    new_dslope -= u_new.slope; // old slope disappeared at this point
                    slope_changes[new_locked.end] = new_dslope;
                }
                // else: we recorded it already in old_dslope
            }
            // Now handle user history
            uint user_epoch = user_point_epoch[_tokenId] + 1;

            user_point_epoch[_tokenId] = user_epoch;
            u_new.ts = block.timestamp;
            u_new.blk = block.number;
            user_point_history[_tokenId][user_epoch] = u_new;
        }
    }

Curve Docs:
https://docs.curve.fi/references/whitepapers/dao/#implemention-details
User voting power
is linearly decreasing since the moment of lock. So does the total voting power
. In order to avoid periodic check-ins, every time the user deposits, or withdraws, or changes the locktime, we record user’s slope and bias for the linear function
in user_point_history. We also change slope and bias for the total voting power
and record in point_history. In addition, when user’s lock is scheduled to end, we schedule change of slopes of
in the future in slope_changes. Every change involves increasing the epoch by 1.
This way we don’t have to iterate over all users to figure out, how much should
change by, neither we require users to check in periodically. However, we limit the end of user locks to times rounded off by whole weeks.
Slopes and biases change both when a user deposits and locks governance tokens, and when the locktime expires. All the possible expiration times are rounded to whole weeks to make number of reads from blockchain proportional to number of missed weeks at most, not number of users (which can be potentially large).

Well the vesting escrow whitepaper explains how it works, well the bias is to calculate the voting power while slope is used part of the calculation of finding the voting weight of user.
I was confused with the Linear Decay formula  f(t) = C - r*t Formula derived from here: https://sciencing.com/write-linear-decay-function-8646603.html
Anyways, do not be confused with voting weight and linear decay formula, both are different.

Give a like, spent quite a while truly understanding it lol
